# Writing a script that automatically forwards emails from a Yahoo Mail address

Tags: email, yahoo-mail, email-forwarding

Starting 1/1/2021 Yahoo Mail is making automatic email forwarding a Premium/Paid Feature for all users. Quite a scummy thing to do in my opinion.

I have looked through some Yahoo API documents, but they are either deprecated, or don't seem to offer integration with Yahoo Mail.

https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html
This explains how to access the API for read/write access to emails, but it seems these features are either behind a paywall or are deprecated. I've kind of hit a dead end.
Either way, I would assume Yahoo would wall off this functionality since they are making it a paid feature...

I'm thinking of maybe trying test automation software to manually forward emails, but that seems like it may get cumbersome.

If anyone has any insight into this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.